# gnome-terminal - open new window instead of finding the existing one

Tags: launcher, gnome-terminal, workspaces

A recent change is that running gnome-terminal (the "Terminal" application) from the launcher now finds an existing window if one is open.  In 18.04, doing this would always open a new terminal window.

This is really annoying.  I typically have half a dozen workspaces open for different things, and when I try to launch a terminal, I want a new one on the workspace I'm on, not to be dragged to a different workspace that happens to have a terminal already open where I then have to create a new terminal window and drag it back to the workspace where I want it.

Is there some way to change back to the old behaviour?

Comment: are you on 19.10 0r 18.04?

Comment: The behavior you describe is not the result of any change, it's the expected behavior and has been for quite some time. (unity and gnome-shell). There is a desktop action on right click on launcher icon that open a new window/terminal.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that all my installs pre 19.10 defaulted to launching a new terminal. I'd hit the windows/super key, type 'term' hit return and a new terminal window would appear. Now it's just finding the one that I didn't want to be typing in. Reminds me of the horrible behaviour that MS introduced in Windows 8 which did much the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Middle-Button on your mouse when you're clicking on the icon. This will open a new instance of that application in gnome.

But I suggest you to make a shortcut for yourself for Terminal because you're going to put your hands on the keyboard anyway. I use `Super` + `Enter` since I use terminal too much!

You can also change the `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Terminal.desktop` and change the `gnome-terminal` exec commands to `gnome-terminal --window`.

Comment: It is also possible to use Gnome Tweaks for setting that clicking an item on the Dash by default launches a new instance rather than switching to an existing instance. Would be good to add that possibility to your answer.

Comment: I didn't know you could set a keyboard shortcut for a terminal - good idea.

Comment: Couldn't find anything in tweaks which seemed to do what I needed, but adding --window has done the trick nicely :)

Comment: Just as an update, adding --window did not fix it. The suggestions of using the middle mouse button is useless to me as the entire point of me bringing up the launcher with a keyboard button press and typing stuff is that specifically do not want to touch the mouse.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Gnome...

- Go to **Extensions**.
- Look down the list for **Launch new instance**.
- Set it to **ON**.

This affects more than the gnome-terminal window but I also find the behaviour of returning to the same terminal window extremely annoying.

An alternative is to hit the context menu button in the currently open terminal window and hit <kbd>T</kbd> (or just <kbd>ENTER</kbd> because it is already on the **Open terminal** menu item at the top of the context menu) for a new terminal window, then do a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>downcursor</kbd> to move the new terminal window into the next available desktop.  I frequently do this when opening multiple terminals already set to the directory I am working in.  Saves all the `cd`'ing you might otherwise do.  If you are using the mouse to do things, it will only slow you down.  I strongly recommend learning your way around keyboard methods of doing things.  Makes things quicker.

Comment: Where these *Extensions* could be found? Do you mean additional GUI tool, that should be downloaded? Then offer a command to install it.

Comment: That seems to be _exactly_ what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04, I can hit `Ctrl` + `Enter` from the launcher and get a new window.